# Excel 2007 - Consolidating non contiguous data from multiple sheets into a master sheet (ie a budget workbook)

Tags: excel

Sorry if this has been asked before, I just don't how to formulate my search query properly and can't find info.

I'm working on a personal budget workbook as a learning experience of Excel.
What I am trying to do is to lookup values in a column, gather all similar values from that column and add the corresponding adjacent cell value and put it all into the "master" sheet.
(Am I explaning it properly?)

Example:

```
code amount
  1   $2.00
  2   $3.00
  1   $4.00
  3   $1.00
  4   $2.00
  2   $1.00
```

I want to have the resulting "master" sheet to show:

```
code total
  1  $6.00
  2  $4.00
  3  $1.00
  4  $2.00
```

I have no knowledge of VBA and was hoping to do this with formulas.
I know the basics of Excel but this is above my current knowledge.
I don't even know how to start about it or where to look.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SUMIF for it. Refer to my image

formula I use for cell G2 is =SUMIF($A$2:$B$7,F2,$B$2:$B$7)

$A$2:$B$7  : is your source data table

F2         :is the cell holding your unique code (1,2,3,4...)

$B$2:$B$7  : is the range that holding the amount

[image: Capture]

(if you cannot see the image, may be your company block this website https://i.stack.imgur.com/ag6O2.png)

Comment: Looking at it from my home PC so no problem with images. Thanks for the steer in the right direction. I will experiment with this formula. I have data on multiple sheets so I guess I will have to add the sheet reference to it. Anyhow, Some fun ahead. Thanks again. I will report back in a few days.